I install Ubuntu 24.04 on my Mac mini 2012 and I have slowly work with “heavy design” web pages
I use a late 2012 mac mini with core i7, 16gb ram, HD Graphics 4000 and ssd.
Apple no longer support this mac mini and I installed ubuntu 24.04. After I started use Ubuntu, I began to notice that loading websites with heavy graphic content greatly slows down my computer, and my mouse begins to move sluggishly. I'm guessing it's a video card driver issue.
If anyone has already encountered this, please give me advice.
$ inxi -G 
Graphics:
  Device-1: Intel 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics driver: i915 v: kernel
  Display: wayland server: X.Org v: 23.2.6 with: Xwayland v: 23.2.6
    compositor: gnome-shell v: 46.0 driver: dri: crocus gpu: i915
    resolution: 3440x1440~60Hz
  API: EGL v: 1.5 drivers: crocus,swrast
    platforms: wayland,x11,surfaceless,device
  API: OpenGL v: 4.5 compat-v: 4.2 vendor: intel mesa v: 24.0.9-0ubuntu0.2
    renderer: Mesa Intel HD Graphics 4000 (IVB GT2)


Please [edit] your question and give more detail. What is your hardware exactly? Are you really trying to use a modern operating system with a computer from 12 years ago? What is the problem you are experiencing? What  is slow? Moving the mouse? Opening a program? Using the program? What graphics card do you have? What driver are you using with it? What is the output of inxi -G?

Done
I would be grateful for any recommendations

Thanks. To be honest, I'm not surprised. You are using a 12 year old computer and trying to load modern websites. You could try using Xorg instead of Wayland, but at the end of the day, I doubt there's much you will be able to do. You can't really use very old hardware for very modern websites.

But this pc with old MacOs work perfect . I had this problem only after updating on ubuntu . Tell me how I can try Xorg ?
And i have 1 more idea about my problem ...I saw a post somewhere on the Internet that after installing a new (not officially supported by Apple) version of MacOS on the same Mac mini, the amount of video RAM changed from 1500 MB to 7 MB, and it was necessary to manually change it back to 1500 mb. How i can check how much RAM used by video card now?
